Confidence interval for solutions of ODE
Given an differential equation whose coefficients and initial conditions are only known to belong to confidence intervals ($\mu_{i}$, $\sigma_{i}$), is there a theory giving the confidence interval for the solution at time t?
Any papers or references is welcome, even for special class of differential equations.

There are theorems about the evolution of ODE solutions based on the initial conditions. See this paper for example. Having more precise answers highly depends on the type of ODE you have.

If the initial conditions follow are distributed according to a density function $f_0(x)$, and the state follows a differential equation $\dot{x} = g(x,t)$, then the density of the state at time $t$, $f(x,t)$, follows the partial differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \nabla_x\cdot (fg)=0, \ f(x,0) = f_0(x).
$$
Depending on $g$ and $f_0$, you can sometimes find analytic expressions for $f(x,t)$ using the method of characteristics. If you have an explicit solution to $\dot{x} = g(x,t)$, then you can use that to construct a formula for $f$. See here for an example with a linear ODE.
Other than doing this, the only other way to get precise quantiles/intervals of interest over time is to numerically simulate many trajectories from initial conditions drawn from $f_0$ or to estimate them using various bounds on the growth of particular ODEs. For nonlinear equations, these bounds tend to be very pessimistic.
